# How to handle token expiry in Single Sign On (SSO)?

Tags: single-sign-on, devops

Have been checking about how the cookie / token is handled at the browser level in an SSO architecture. Once the Identity provider sends a response to a service provider (Application), say APP1. If the user opens an app APP2, it is redirected to the app skipping the log in as the IDP verifies the cookie provided. What are the methods for the service providers to get notified if the IDP token is expired or out of scope?

Comment: The methods vary based on protocol (which you did not specify) and aren't very good. What are you trying to achieve? See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm planning to use JWT tokens or OAuth 2.0. Just want to know how the token expiry in the IDP is notified to the service applications. Is it via a database trigger or are there any other ways to handle it?

Comment: I hope you mean OpenID Connect (OIDC) - see [OIDC Session Management](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) for suggestions on how to handle it.